# Linear Inequality Implies Log Inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Imagine I have three sets of strictly positive real numbers: $a_i,b_i,c_i>0$, $\forall i=1,\ldots,n$. For finite $n$. And further that the following inequality holds:
\begin{align}
\sum_i a_i \leq \sum_i b_i + \sum_i c_i
\end{align}
Then does the following inequality hold?
\begin{align}
\sum_i \log(1+a_i) \leq \sum_i \log(1+b_i) + \sum_i \log(1+c_i)
\end{align}

Comment: My intuition says 'yes'

Comment: You could represent it : $\prod{(a_{i}+1)} \le \prod{(c_{i}+1)}\prod{(b_{i}+1)} $